# ejabberd doen't work because erl.exe always crash

Tags: crash, erlang, ejabberd, erl

I have installed ejabberd 15.07.40, but it doen't work because erl.exe always crash.

From application log I see a lot of the following events:

```
Event[0]:
  Log Name: Application
  Source: Windows Error Reporting
  Date: 2020-04-23T09:47:39.937
  Event ID: 1001
  Task: N/A
  Level: Information
  Opcode: Info
  Keyword: Classic
  User: N/A
  User Name: N/A
  Computer: *********
  Description: 
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: BEX64
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: erl.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 551aa60d
P4: beam.smp.dll
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 551aa532
P7: 000000000018e757
P8: c0000409
P9: 0000000000000000
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_erl.exe_bb203c89213ececa76b19504fffeade88d17aa_04f44524_433845c0
```

And

```
Event[2]:
  Log Name: Application
  Source: Application Error
  Date: 2020-04-23T09:47:27.971
  Event ID: 1000
  Task: Application Crashing Events
  Level: Error
  Opcode: Info
  Keyword: Classic
  User: N/A
  User Name: N/A
  Computer: *********
  Description: 
Faulting application name: erl.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x551aa60d
Faulting module name: beam.smp.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x551aa532
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000018e757
Faulting process id: 0x48b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d619436ecbf5e2
Faulting application path: D:\Avaya\Contact Center\EnterpriseWebChat\eJabberd\bin\erl.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Avaya\Contact Center\EnterpriseWebChat\eJabberd\bin\beam.smp.dll
Report Id: dc2a5d19-c4a0-4870-af0e-9a201e1a403a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

As far as I understand, error c0000409 means "Stack buffer overflow". But the second error is unknown for me.

I tried enable debug log level for ejabberd, but no any usefull info were added to the log file.
Is it possible to clarify root cause of these issues?

**Update**
I checked erl crash dump and see slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k
As far as I see net_kernel start failed. 
What can I check to find reason of this?

Comment: ejabberd 15.07 is almost five years old. Is there any particular reason you can't use a newer version?

Comment: My product is old and big. Update of ejabberd requires full regression testing. I'm ready to update it, but the first of all I need  confirm that current issue caused by old ejabberd. It works fine on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?
erl -name aaa
then
net_kernel:start([...])

You may have no epmd running, that'll be what the econnrefused is about. When you start net_kernel it wants to register a name with epmd so the node is findable.

Comment: Hi @虫大侠, I tried perform your commands and saw the following:
`\eJabberd\bin>erl -name aaa
Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
(aaa@bbb.hostname.com)1> net_kernel:start([aaa])
_`
But behaviour didn't chanched. It is good output?

Comment: Your startup script may be wrong, what command did you execute to start